# How to stop the loop when the same values appear in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, while-loop

[image: screenshot of my task]

Above is my task. I have to stop the loop when the same items appear in the list, and then I have to sum them.

```
def squareA(a,b):
  res = []
  z = 0

  while z!= 3:

     res.insert(0,(a + z)**2)
     res.insert(0,(b - z)**2)
     z += 1

  print(res)
  res = list(dict.fromkeys(res))
  print(res)
  res = sum(res)

  return res

a = 5
b = 6
print(squareA(a,b))
```

Comment: For example, when I input a = 5 , b = 6 My program just square and sum them, but when i have a  = 1 and b =4 , sum look like 1 + 16 + 9 + 4 = 30

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  You haven't described your problem.  As far as I can guess, you want us to teach you how to analyze and solve the general problem; this would be out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: pogiloyded: Put the description of the problem _in your question_.

Comment: Image of the excercise above

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overthinking this. Rather than appending the squares from both ends - working up from a and down from b simultaneously, you can just do something like the following:

```
def square(a, b):
    rv = a**2
    for i in range(a, b):
        rv+= (i+1)**2
    return rv
```

or using lists as in your example code:

```
def square(a, b):
    rv = [a**2]
    for i in range(a, b):
        rv.append((i+1)**2)
    return sum(rv)
```